# Setting the alignment of the contents in a UIPickerview in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How can I set the text alignement of the choices I see within my UIPickerView to be center aligned?  I've tried setting almost everything I can, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom class that inherited from UIPickerViewModel.  This read my data off my SQLite file, converted the text to UILabels, and added them to an array of UILabels.  I formatted it so that the text was bold, centered, and colored to my liking.  When it was displayed in the UIPickerView these formatting changes carried over and they were displayed as I had hoped!